# How to start Firebase emulator?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-tools

How can I start a Firebase Emulator, I have performed all the steps mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup). Here is my output when I try to run the emulator:

```
=== Emulators Setup
? Which Firebase emulators do you want to set up? Press Space to select emulator
s, then Enter to confirm your choices. Firestore
i  Port for firestore already configured: 8080
? Would you like to download the emulators now? Yes

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
users-iMac:~ users firebase emulators:start --only firestore
i  emulators: Starting emulators: firestore
⚠  emulators: It seems that you are running multiple instances of the emulator suite for project project_name. This may result in unexpected behavior.
✔  hub: emulator hub started at http://localhost:4400
⚠  firestore: Did not find a Cloud Firestore rules file specified in a firebase.json config file.
⚠  firestore: The emulator will default to allowing all reads and writes. Learn more about this option: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#security_rules_configuration.
i  firestore: firestore emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
✔  firestore: firestore emulator started at http://localhost:8080
i  firestore: For testing set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080
✔  emulators: All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

On clicking on the localhost link (`localhost: 4400`), it shows:

[image]

And on `localhost:8080` it shows:

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same issue. I asked in the firebase subreddit, and if I get an answer there, I will post it here as well.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and it appears that the hub does not work on firebase versions less than 8.4, and you are using 8.1.1. Try upgrading to 8.4.3.